# NetSuite formula text extract characters from string

Tags: formula, netsuite, saved-searches

For NetSuite, I have a text field shown below:

"Three Phase Power Requirement:
Voltage(VAC): 208,
Max Power(VA): 24638,
Max Current/Phase(A): 68,
Circuit Breaker(A): 80"

I am trying to write a formula which extracts the values below, such as "208", "24638", etc..

What type of formula would need to be used to extract these characters into a Formula(text)? Any examples are appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

ADD  FORMULA(TEXT) field  and add this in formula: `REGEXP_SUBSTR({purchasedescription}, '[Voltage(VAC):  ](\d+)',2,1,'c',1)`

Another  FORMULA(TEXT)

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR({purchasedescription}, '[Max Power(VA):  ](\d+)',2,2,'c',1)
```

[image]